# Question about vectors and span

Tags: linear-algebra

imo I think these three statements are wrong, pls correct me if I'm wrong.

1. A set with exactly n vectors must span $\mathbb R^n$. (Wrong because what if the vectors are linearly dependent to each other?)
2. A set of more than $n$ vectors,let say $4$ vectors must span $\mathbb R^3$. (Wrong, If none of the vectors are linearly dependent to each other, then it will span $\mathbb R^4$)
3. A set of more than n vectors and none of them is a multiple of the other must span $\mathbb R^n$. (Wrong, it should span $\mathbb R^{n+i}$, $(i=1,2,3 ,\dots )$

Answer (score 1):

In the first two cases the vectors could be dependent.  In the third, let's investigate $\Bbb R^3$.  We could have $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0),(1,2,0)\}$, and the span would be two dimensional.  This should generalize.

In fact, I think in part $3$ that the span would only have to be two-dimensional.

Comment: Indeed you could choose infinitely (even uncountably) many vectors on, say, the unit circle in any two-dimensional plane, and they will still only span that plane.

Comment: @Bungo Right you are.